# Can't see log messages of program when using ESAPI

Tags: java, security, logging, esapi

I am a new user of ESAPI
I created the ESAPI properties correctly (I think), the encryption and decryption works.

However, I no longer see the log messages of the original code (it's a map/reduce program).
This is the property in ESAPI.properties:

```
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory
```

The logger is slf4j, but I tried changing it to log4j.

I thought about using org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory, but it is security related and my code obviously has more to log than just security events.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/reference/Log4JLogFactory.java#Log4JLogFactory):

```
 //Note that you must specify the LogFactory in either log4j.properties:
 //log4j.loggerFactory=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLoggerFactory 

 //log4j.xml: <loggerFactory class="org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLoggerFactory"/>
```

You need your log4j implementation to specifically pull in the esapi log factory for this to work as expected.